# Refactoring getters Vue.js (Vuex)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to refactor two getters in vuex. In my state I have some hard coded array of objects like this:

```js
 state: {
    color: 'All colors',
    size: 'All sizes',

    allShoes: [
      {
        productId: 1,
        productno: 1234,
        type: 'sneakers',
        brand: 'Nike',
        model: 'Air Zoom',
        gender: 'Men',
        size: ['39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45'],
        price: 120,
        color: 'red',
        outerMaterial: 'Textile',
        lining: 'Textile',
        sole: 'Textile',
        casingThickness: 'Thin lining',
        fabric: 'Knitwear',
        colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
        image: require('@/assets/images/nike-air-zoom.jpg'),
      },
      {
        productId: 2,
        productno: 1235,
        type: 'sneakers',
        brand: 'Adidas',
        model: 'Ultra Boost',
        gender: 'Men',
        size: ['41', '42', '43', '44', '45'],
        price: 130,
        color: 'white',
        outerMaterial: 'Textile',
        lining: 'Textile',
        sole: 'Textile',
        casingThickness: 'Thin lining',
        fabric: 'Knitwear',
        colors: ['red', 'blue', 'orange'],
        image: require('@/assets/images/adidas-ultra.jpg'),
      },
```

[You can see the full application here](https://sneakerstorevue.netlify.app/)

As you can see I want to filter my products by color and size. That works just fine with the following getters:

```js
  getters: {
    getProductById: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.allShoes.find((shoe) => shoe.productId === id);
    },
    getProductsByGender: (state) => (gender) => {
      if (state.color === 'All colors' && state.size === 'All sizes') {
        return state.allShoes.filter((shoe) => shoe.gender === gender);
      } else {
        return state.allShoes.filter((shoe) => {
          return (
            (state.color === 'All colors' ||
              (shoe.color === state.color && shoe.gender === gender)) &&
            (state.size === 'All sizes' || shoe.size.includes(state.size)) &&
            shoe.gender === gender
          );
        });
      }
    },
    getProductsByType: (state) => (type) => {
      if (state.color === 'All colors' && state.size === 'All sizes') {
        return state.allShoes.filter((shoe) => shoe.type === type);
      } else {
        return state.allShoes.filter((shoe) => {
          return (
            (state.color === 'All colors' ||
              (shoe.color === state.color && shoe.type === type)) &&
            (state.size === 'All sizes' || shoe.size.includes(state.size)) &&
            shoe.type === type
          );
        });
      }
    },
  }
```

The problem I am having is that this is kind of a duplicate code and I would like to refactor the getProductsByGender and getProductsByType getters into one. In the getProductsByGender I am using the filter array method but I need to access the shoe.gender in my object. In the getProductsByType I need to access the shoe.type. I can't figure out a way to refactor these two getters or maybe it's ok to use them like this? It feels like im not following the DRY principle. Is there a way to use a mixin maybe? I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your function itself is bad. You can indeed boil it down to just one though.
Keep in mind that if your page should be getting several thousand items you should consider doing this on the backend with some form of search-engine (elastic, algolia).

```js
products(options) {
  if (state.color === "All colors" && state.size == "All sizes") {
    return state.allShoes.filter((shoe) => shoe[options.category] === options.filter);
  } else {
    return state.allShoes.filter((shoe) => {
      return (
        (state.color === "All colors" ||
          (shoe.color === state.color && shoe[options.category] === options.filter)) &&
        (state.size === "All sizes" || shoe.size.includes(state.size)) &&
        shoe[options.category] === options.filter
      );
    });
  }
}

// Example to call the function
const products = this.products({
  category: "gender",
  filter: "Female",
});
```

Comment: I can see what you are doing here by passing an objoect as parameter. This is my first vuex project. So I tried to put the products function outside of state in my vuex module and then calling it inside the getProductsByGender getter and returning products. The problem is that the products function returns undefined.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't want to put the actual data in Vuex since it seems page-related. You'd normally query that data once you land on that specific page instead of holding onto all the items the whole time. If this is just a playground-example-situation its okay. To be honest the trick about the function is to use `shoe[variableParam]` so you can query anything. With a setup like this you're not limited to `type` or `gender`. You could query for any property in your dataset. You could also re-write it as a vuex-action instead of a getter and just call it once the user lands on the page

Comment: If you have any more issues with that kinda setup, please create a simple codesandbox. It's a lot easier to debug and make changes to

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose this kind of setup because im am wotking on building a front end portfolio so I dont have any backend skills and I couldn't find any useful api:s to fetch this kind of data from. I don'n know if it helps but I have a github repo at [link](https://github.com/ChristianPredoianu/Sneaker-store-Vue.js-Vuex-) which I uploaded to codesandbox at  [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-hill-ep27o?) But for some reason the preview doesn't work. You can see the setup I tried in the store. I don't know if it helps though.

Comment: My application works as intended to be honest, the only thing I can't get my arms around is the refactoring of those getters which I think look like quite a wet code.

Comment: Yea, after cloning your repo my solution isn't what you want since it doesn't rely on getters. I personally would get rid of the store/products.js entirely and move the data to your `/views/`. It's fine to mock the data using hardcoded JSON but this isn't a use-case for vuex. You can just pass your data down to your `SneakerShoes.vue`. It would make it a lot cleaner to handle your data directly where you want it displayed instead of a global state. Since this isn't really a discussion section, feel free to send me a DM at http://reddit.com/u/leiinth if you have any specific questions